# Иконки в кнопках

Tags: jquery-mobile, иконки, html, css3, css

У меня сделан сайт на jquery mobile. И мне бы хотелось в кнопку вставить СВОЮ иконку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в своих стилях на класс кнопки повешайте свой бекграунд и при необходимости поставьте !important, то есть перекройте стандартный класс своим. Или зайдите в файл jquery.mobile.css или как он называется, найдите тот класс и измените его бекграунд